# How do I install gRPC for electron version 4.0.x

Tags: node.js, electron, grpc

Installed **electron@4.0.0** (also tried @4.0.7) and installed **grpc** and **@grpc/proto-loade**r. When I launch electron I get a runtime error

> Uncaught Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
>       Expected directory: electron-v4.0-darwin-x64-unknown
>       Found: [node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown]
>       This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system

Of course I tried running the suggested solution, `npm rebuild`, but that did not solve the problem. I also tried rebuilding the grpc module

```
npm rebuild grpc --build-from-source --runtime=electron --target=4.0.0 --target_archx64 --dturl=https://atom.io/download/electron
```

I tried uninstalling everything and starting from scratch. We're cloning the electron quick start repo and so after cloning and installing modules I installed grpc targeting a specific version

```
npm install grpc --runtime=electron --target=<electron version>
```

Which resulted in the same error so then I tried rebuilding

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild // to rebuild grpc module
```

And if I delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then re-install `npm install` I get a success message (don't pay attention to the version, I'm watching my versions are matching) which looks like the "missing" module was installed

> node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
>   [grpc]
>
> Success: "/../electron/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote
>
> protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall /../electron/node_modules/protobufjs
>   node scripts/postinstall
>
> electron@4.0.8 postinstall /../electron/node_modules/electron
>   node install.js

Comment: You are building for Electron 4.0.0 but installing Electron 4.0.8. Not sure if that could cause the error, though. Maybe you should rebuild `grpc ` *after* installing it (and after installing `electron-rebuild`) ?

Comment: No, when I install a specific version of electron I target that version. The last install jumped to @4.0.8 for some reason

Comment: I redid everything. I'm cloning the electron quick start repo and now it's @4.0.7 and getting the same error that grpc was compiled against a different node version NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64 vs NODE_MODULE_VERSION 69

Comment: Do you compile grpc as the last thing before starting the app ? Also, why do you leave `<electron version>` in the `npm install grpc` command, instead of giving the version like you do in the first command ?

Comment: It's pseudo code. I put the target in the command.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/762

Still, the solution I tried is the solution I needed. Not sure what I was doing wrong initially!

For future Googlers the summary is this:

> The grpc_node module seems to be compiled for NODE_MODULE_VERSION=64,
>   but Electron 4 since 4.0.4 switched ... to
>   specifying NODE_MODULE_VERSION=69 and there is a mismatch at runtime
>   trying to load the module.

So, what I did to solve was

- Clone the electron quick start repo
- Uninstall the version of electron that came with quick start
- Install electron@4.0.0
- Install gRPC with target to 4.0.0

  npm install grpc --runtime=electron --target=4.0.0